# Batch : label length

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering about the maximum length of a label in a batch file.

I found [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/63071/en-us) stating:

> MS-DOS recognizes only the first eight characters of a batch file label; subsequent characters are ignored.

They also provide an example :

```
@echo off
goto latestch
:latestchanges
echo two
:latestch
echo three
```

which is supposed to output

```
two
three
```

instead of

```
three
```

But on my system, I get

```
three
```

I tried on Windows 7 (6.1.7600) and WindowsXP (5.1.2600), and get the same result on both of them.

It looks to me there is no eight characters limitation!
Am I missing something?

Comment: I know it's been answered, but the root cause of the confusion is MS-DOS versus the windows command lien

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The limits are 2047 and 8192, depending on your OS. See [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473).

Comment: According to the KB, the limit doesn't depend on 32 vs 64 bit; 2047 characters for Windows NT4/2000, 8191 for Windows XP and later

Comment: Be sure to Look at M M. 's answer if you want to understand the `Why`

Comment: This is simply wrong. Those values apply to the maximum command line length and the maximum variable value length. But the max label length is much lower.

Comment: The question was about msdos, not a windows cmd.exe

Answer (score 8):

The example is true for `MS-DOS` not `cmd.exe`. The version of your `cmd.exe` is higher than `MS-DOS`. Feel free to use any length of label.

According to that article, this limitation is valid for :

> ```
> Microsoft MS-DOS 4.01 Standard Edition
> Microsoft MS-DOS 5.0 Standard Edition
> Microsoft MS-DOS 5.0a
> Microsoft MS-DOS 6.0 Standard Edition
> Microsoft MS-DOS 6.2 Standard Edition
> Microsoft MS-DOS 6.21 Standard Edition
> Microsoft MS-DOS 6.22 Standard Edition
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Windows cmd.exe supports label lengths up to 128 characters long (including the leading colon). Any characters after 128 are simply ignored.

So a label length 500 will match a label length 300 if the first 128 characters of both labels is the same.

Here is a batch script that demonstrates the behavior:

```
@echo off

call :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 125
call :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 126
call :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 127
call :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 128
call :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 129
call :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 130

exit /b

:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo %1 finds 125
exit /b

:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo %1 finds 126
exit /b

:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo %1 finds 127
exit /b

:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo %1 finds 128
exit /b

:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo %1 finds 129
exit /b

:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo %1 finds 130
exit /b
```

-- OUTPUT --

```
125 finds 125
126 finds 126
127 finds 127
128 finds 128
129 finds 128
130 finds 128
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the 8 character limitation went away when Windows moved away from the MS-DOS platform after Windows 98.  All Microsoft OSes starting with Windows 2000 no longer have the limitation.  The command window that we see today in Windows 7 and others is an application that runs on top of Windows, rather than the older implementation where the command window accessed the MS-DOS layer running beneath Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 CMD and BAT batch commands that use the `GOTO :LABEL` are not limited to 8 characters following the ":" character as initially noted by the original poster when they are executed directly or CALLed from another batch file.

i.e.,

```
@echo off
SET VARIABLE=2
if %VARIABLE%.==.  GOTO :LABELNUMBERZERO
if %VARIABLE%.==1. GOTO :LABELNUMBERONE
if %VARIABLE%.==2. GOTO :LABELNUMBERTWO
if %VARIABLE%.==3. GOTO :LABELNU
if %VARIABLE%.==4. GOTO :LABELN
GOTO :ENDTHISLONGTHING
:LABELNUMBERZERO
echo your variable was " "
GOTO :ENDTHISLONGTHING
:LABELNUMBERONE
echo your variable was "1"
GOTO :ENDTHISLONGTHING
:LABELNUMBERTWO
echo your variable was "2"
:ENDTHISLONGTHING
:LABELNU
echo your variable was "3"
:ENDTHISLONGTHING
:LABELN
echo your variable was "4"
:ENDTHISLONGTHING
```

The result of this is:
    your variable was "2"

If I `set` the `VARIABLE=4` the result is:
    your variable was "4"

So DOS now sees even similarly named (beginning characters) as unique labels even if the same contents of a shorter label exist in the batch file beforehand.