# In a batch script, is there a documented length limit for Labels and the text which appears _after_ the Label?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, string-length

Consider the following Label with text added after to clarify what the arguments are for in a batch script (anything after a space is ignored . . .):

```
:LineBuilder [1 - main var type 1] [2 - main var type 2] [3 - subvar type] [4 - string to store in 1.3] [5 - Option for giving the length vs needing to calculate it] [6 - var containing Width to pull from] [7 - var containing Blanks to pull from] [8 - Option to add CRLF at the end of string] [9 - Border Option] [10 - Option to justify text 1/left, 2/right, 3/split - right text supplied Arg4, 4/centered, 5/split - left text supplied Arg5] [11 - Left portion of Text if Justy is split [spaces in between text]]
```

Referring to this [SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611917/batch-label-length), I know the maximum length of the *`Label` itself* is 128 characters.  Is it also documented how long the length of the text ***after*** the label can be?  If not officially documented, or if this specific question is not already answered, I may have the answer, but want to confirm it's not listed somewhere else.

Not including the colon (`:`), the entire line is 511 characters.  The length of the string afterward, including all spaces (and the space separating the `arg clarifications` from the `Label` itself) is 500 characters long.  How I ended up stumbling upon this was getting an error which took me a while to pinpoint!  It appeared the CMD Line Interpreter gave up attempting to store the `Label's` string data in one single string anymore, and attempted to parse the final `]` as a Command!  (If you add a `REM`  just after the first place, the error changes to `ext]]` - an increase of exactly 4 characters.

> ```
> ']' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

Experiencing this in Windows 10.

#### Update

Based on jeb's answer below, and the question in the comments, I can attest the file is saved as `CR LF` line endings (Verified as shown in NotePad++, Encoding's `UTF-8` *(does this make a difference?)*. . .

Minimal example showing where it's in use:

```cmd
REM <<<-_-_-_-_-_END :OtherRoutine_-_-_-_-_->>>
 REM Description Box 
 
 REM Other "SubRoutine Code"

 Call :LineBuilder "consolText" "consol" "lineOne" "Searching for Corrupted Files.  Please wait." "44" "consol.width" "consol.blanks" "1" "0" "1" ""

 REM Other "SubRoutine Code"
 Goto :EOF
REM <<<-_-_-_-_-_END :OtherRoutine_-_-_-_-_->>>

REM ╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
REM ║  -LineBuilder-                                       ║
REM ║Sets the variable for specified line to equal the text║
REM ║supplied, takes the line variable, gets the string    ║
REM ║length, and then calls ComputeLineLen to establish the║
REM ║total console's line length to set the blanks. Then it║
REM ║sets the line's blanks length and establishes the     ║
REM ║fully computed line for output in MainPrompt, with    ║
REM ║the spaces justified left, right, split, or centered. ║
REM ╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

REM <<<-_-_-_-_-_BEGIN :LineBuilder_-_-_-_-_->>>
 :LineBuilder [1 - main var type 1] [2 - main var type 2] [3 - subvar type] [4 - string to store in 1.3] [5 - Option for giving the length vs needing to calculate it] [6 - var containing Width to pull from] [7 - var containing Blanks to pull from] [8 - Option to add CRLF at the end of string] [9 - Border Option] [10 - Option to justify text 1/left, 2/right, 3/split - right text supplied Arg4, 4/centered, 5/split - left text supplied Arg5] [11 - Left portion of Text if Justy is split [spaces in between text]]
 
 <nul (set /p "lineOut= LineBuilder:!cr!!lf!")>>%log%
 <nul (set /p "lineOut= LineBuilder:!cr!!lf!")>>%formLog%

 REM More Code
 Goto :EOF
REM <<<-_-_-_-_-_END :LineBuilder_-_-_-_-_->>>
```

If I change the text after the label to be the following, the error goes away:

```
 :LineBuilder [1 - main var type 1] [2 - main var type 2] [3 - subvar type] [4 - string to store in 1.3] [5 - Option for giving the length vs needing to calculate it] [6 - var containing Width to pull from] [7 - var containing Blanks to pull from] [8 - Option to add CRLF at end of string] [9 - Border Option] [10 - Option to justify text 1/left, 2/right, 3/split - right text supplied Arg4, 4/centered, 5/split - left text supplied Arg5] [11 - Left/right Text if Justy is split [spaces in text]]
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue on Windows 11. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: My operating system is Windows 10.  Added this information along with a tag to the question for clarity.

Comment: [The maximum length for a label is 127 characters, no spaces](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) (doesn't fully explain your issue though)

Comment: Yeah - I was wondering about this too - hence my reference to the SO article (where it was tested to show 128 ... Not concerned about the negligible difference).  Just very curious this is happening.  I don't know if it happened simply because of the structure of the data after the label or not

Comment: World of Wonders... Btw: I can't replicate (Win11), even when I triple your argument string (the label ends at the first space, the rest of the line *should* be ignored)

Comment: Why was this question closed?  Please point me to the exact statement where I'm `seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more` - I do not understand how any of the question could be misconstrued this way.

Comment: Well, unless you simply want a boolean answer, _(which would not really be on topic here)_, "Is this documeted anywhere?" looks pretty much like a statement seeking exactly that!

Comment: What doesn't make sense though, is across countless questions, there's speak of `undocumented` items from `cmd.exe` - so the answer to that question is simply a "Yes" or a "No" - if I had asked "What's the best documented answer to this question?" then I could see this as seeking a recommendation.  I'm seeking a factual stated answer - if it isn't documented, where on earth would one search to find the answer if not here?  Asking "Is this documented anywhere?" is asking just that - for a truthful answer so as not to waste any further time expecting an answer here when I can read documentation.

Comment: I just looked at the question again - I'll remove the question at the end since this _SHOULD_ be the only question that could be misconstrued. . .

Comment: @Stephan, does your string at the end of the label also contain Brackets?

Comment: yes, tried with your stated command and when it didn't spit errors, I just doubled and finally tripled the "arguments" string (still ending with `]]`) - still no errors. (Meanwhile I had a chance to try it on Win10 too - same behaviour: no errors)

Comment: Hmmmm.  Would changing the code page make a difference?  I'm running `chcp 65001` at the beginning of the batch file because I am using `extended DOS Ascii` characters for a progress bar.  Also, `enabledelayedexpansion` and `enableextensions` are set global for the whole file too.

Comment: `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `chcp 65001` make no difference for me. Still working fine on Win10 and Win11.

Comment: The error description remembers me at the linux line ending character problem. It happens on 256 or 512 byte boundaries when LF instead of CR/LF is used. Btw. A line should not be longer than ~ 8191+cmd tokensize . It's possible, but then more obscure problems arises

Comment: Please add a complete minimal batch file example, where the problem occurs

Comment: I have no idea why, but now I can replicate the problem (very same code as before) Your first label didn't show the error (the line was exactly 512 chars), but in your added code, you have a space in front of the colon, which makes the line 513 chars, revealing your stated error. This *does* explain why my first try ran fine, but it *does not* explain why it worked fine with adding more chars. I haven't found any source mentioning a 512-byte limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minimal example for long label lines:

```
@echo off
goto :myLabel

:myLabel xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx12345678
```

The output is '345678' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

In the label line, the text "1234578" starts after 512 leading characters (the colon label name and many x's).

Probably the label parser has a buffer for 512 bytes (+2 for CRLF), when there is no CRLF found in that buffer, it simply stops searching for CRLF and just use the following characters.

The rule is: If the line of a label is longer than 514 bytes, the parser simply assumes the next command at position 514.

You should solve your problem by just move your description to the next line, btw. that is much more readable than one ultra long line.

```
:LineBuilder 
::: [1 - main var type 1] 
::: [2 - main var type 2]
::: [3 - subvar type] 
::: [4 - string to store in 1.3] 
::: [5 - Option for giving the length vs needing to calculate it] 
::: [6 - var containing Width to pull from] 
::: [7 - var containing Blanks to pull from] 
::: [8 - Option to add CRLF at the end of string]
::: [9 - Border Option]
::: [10 - Option to justify text 1/left, 2/right, 3/split - right text supplied Arg4, 4/centered, 5/split - left text supplied Arg5] 
::: [11 - Left portion of Text if Justy is split [spaces in between text]]
```

For speed reasons, it's better to move the description before the label.

---

Another expample for this kind of problem, but this is **related to line endings**

```
@echo off

goto :LineBuilder
REM 12345678
:LineBuilder [1 - main var type 1] [2 - main var type 2] [3 - subvar type] [4 - string to store in 1.3] [5 - Option for giving the length vs needing to calculate it] [6 - var containing Width to pull from] [7 - var containing Blanks to pull from] [8 - Option to add CRLF at the end of string] [9 - Border Option] [10 - Option to justify text 1/left, 2/right, 3/split - right text supplied Arg4, 4/centered, 5/split - left text supplied Arg5] [11 - Left portion of Text if Justy is split [spaces in between text]]
```

Save this with LF line endings (With vscode you can switch between CRLF and LF)

Then you get:

> 'etween' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

The "unknown" command only depends on the count of characters in the REM line.

**How to solve?**

Save the file with CRLF line endings or use

```
more defectBatch.bat > workingBatch.bat
```

Comment: I am using NotePad++, Line endings are CRLF.  I will add this to the content of the question, but this is great to know in case there's ever a specific niche that someone encounters this!

Comment: Also just confirmed via RegEx search that the lines in question also end with `\r\n` just in case a previous RegEx find/replace in NPP caused the issue

Comment: To be ultra thorough on what you suggested, I have also used the command to output the file content into a "fixed" version of the batch file, then ran `FileCompare` via `CMD` and it found no differences between the original nor the "fixed" version of the file.

Comment: @k1dfr0std You're are right, my suggestion only solves problems when the wrong line endings are used. for your problem the solution is to reduce the line length

Comment: Wonderfully put in the update to your answer!  I used to put the "Parameters" in lines above the Label, but having been working in more robust languages like VB.Net, I've tried to keep my code as similarly structured as I can, hence putting back to the same line as the label.  Glad to find a new limitation within `CMD`!  This next question may warrant its own question, but with the advent of this knowledge of 512 Characters being the max - Will the code execute faster if I were to put the Parameters on the Lines preceding the Label, or leave them immediately after the label?

Comment: @k1dfr0std Btw. I found [a post from 2019](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=58895#p58895) that already described the behavior (And it's by myself). In the tread are also descriptions for other strange effects

Comment: This was a great read!  The other post also answered another lingering question - "does it matter if the parameters are listed before or after the label?" to wit - "Nope." - the effect would still be the same.  Great deal.